# Bounce processing webhook gets error "Failed to verify signature" in Mailgun

Tags: civimail

Have mailgun extension and added mail account for bounce processing with mailgunDB as protocol and my API (using private API) as password.
Every time a mailing goes through it has an error "failed to verify signature" and the details are about the webhook I added in mailgun. ..

***ERROR***
message:            Failed to verify signature
code:

***LAST ERROR***
Array
(
    [type] => 2
    [message] => fopen(api/v3/MailSettings/Getoptions.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
    [file] => /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/File.php
    [line] => 431
)

***ANONYMOUS USER***
REMOTE_ADDR: 54.149.33.164
HTTP_USER_AGENT: mailgun/treq-16.12.0

***SESSION***
CiviCRM:            Array
(
)

***SERVER***
SERVER_SOFTWARE:    Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
REQUEST_URI:        /civicrm/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/mailgun/bounce&reset=1
REDIRECT_HTTPS:     on
REDIRECT_SSL_TLS_SNI:****
REDIRECT_STATUS:    200
HTTPS:              on
SSL_TLS_SNI:        ****
CONTENT_LENGTH:     1672
HTTP_HOST:          ****
CONTENT_TYPE:       application/json
HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING:gzip
HTTP_ACCEPT:        */*
HTTP_USER_AGENT:    mailgun/treq-16.12.0
PATH:               /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
SERVER_SIGNATURE:   Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) Server at ****

SERVER_NAME:        ****
SERVER_ADDR:        xxx
SERVER_PORT:        xxx
REMOTE_ADDR:        xxx
DOCUMENT_ROOT:      /var/www/html/wordpress
REQUEST_SCHEME:     https
CONTEXT_PREFIX:
CONTEXT_DOCUMENT_ROOT:/var/www/html/wordpress
SERVER_ADMIN:       admin@example.com
SCRIPT_FILENAME:    /var/www/html/wordpress/index.php
REMOTE_PORT:        56852
REDIRECT_URL:       /civicrm/
REDIRECT_QUERY_STRING:page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/mailgun/bounce&reset=1
GATEWAY_INTERFACE:  CGI/1.1
SERVER_PROTOCOL:    HTTP/1.1
REQUEST_METHOD:     POST
QUERY_STRING:       page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/mailgun/bounce&reset=1
SCRIPT_NAME:        /index.php
PHP_SELF:           /index.php
REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT: 1561936897.072
REQUEST_TIME:       1561936897

***BACKTRACE***

```
#0 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/ca.bidon.reporterror/CRM/ReportError/Utils.php(31): reporterror_civicrm_generatereport("DOMAIN", (Array:2), NULL, (Array:0))
#1 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/ca.bidon.reporterror/CRM/ReportError/Handler/FormsNoReferer.php(54): CRM_ReportError_Utils::sendReport((Array:2), (Array:0))
#2 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/ca.bidon.reporterror/reporterror.php(168): CRM_ReportError_Handler_FormsNoReferer::handler((Array:2), (Array:0))
#3 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Error.php(372): reporterror_civicrm_handler((Array:2))
#4 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/uk.teamsinger.civicrm.mailgun-master/CRM/Mailgun/Utils.php(30): CRM_Core_Error::fatal("Failed to verify signature")
#5 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/uk.teamsinger.civicrm.mailgun-master/CRM/Mailgun/Page/HandleBounceWebhook.php(19): CRM_Mailgun_Utils::checkSignature(NULL, NULL, NULL)
#6 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(311): CRM_Mailgun_Page_HandleBounceWebhook->run((Array:3), NULL)
#7 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(85): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem((Array:13))
#8 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(52): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke((Array:3))
#9 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1392): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke((Array:3))
#10 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/includes/civicrm.basepage.php(365): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()
#11 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(286): CiviCRM_For_WordPress_Basepage->basepage_handler(Object(WP))
#12 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(310): WP_Hook->apply_filters(FALSE, (Array:1))
#13 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php(531): WP_Hook->do_action((Array:1))
#14 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp.php(750): do_action_ref_array("wp", (Array:1))
#15 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php(1105): WP->main("")
#16 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php(16): wp()
#17 /var/www/html/wordpress/index.php(17): require("/var/www/html/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php")
#18 {main}
```

Comment: I've tried to use the extension on a Drupal7 based CiviCRM and got the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

That extension hasn't been updated in a while and it looks like mailgun used to send signature parameters as request parameters and now has changed and sends them as part of a  json payload. So it looks like the extension needs to be updated for that.

Comment: Is there any way to get bounce info when using mailgun?

Comment: I guess you can log in to the mailgun portal to look it up manually. Otherwise somebody has to write some code somewhere. You could also try contacting the sponsor for that extension and see what they are doing - it looks like they still use civicrm: https://www.whirledcinema.com/contact

Comment: I also need this - may be able to provide some funding to assist. Is anyone going to contact the developer? (thanks for the tip, @demerit)

Comment: Netzih already filed an issue (https://github.com/teamsinger/uk.teamsinger.civicrm.mailgun/issues/23) but if the developer is no longer maintaining it then they may not see it. So that's why I suggested the sponsor org, since probably either they have an updated one or maybe they are no longer using mailgun.